# How to accurately count actual number of lines in a parquet file excluding headers, footers, rowgrups and other metadata

Tags: .net, file, line, counter, parquet

I've a parquet file, which is extract out of sql server table. My task is to count the number of lines in the parquet file. My Sql server table has 9 rows, but when I count the number of lines using .NET, i'm getting 30. Is there any special I need to consider? Below is my .NET code snippet. Also, when I open a file in parquet viwer, I get 9 rows as well. But it looks like program is considering other metadata information available in the parquet file into the number of lines.

int count = 0;
System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(blobClient.OpenRead());

```
            Task<int> task = ComputeDataFromFileAsync(streamReader);
            task.Wait();
            count = Convert.ToInt32(task.Result);
           

            TimeTaken = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime).TotalSeconds * 1.00) / 60), 2);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished Processing " + currFileName + " Count: " + count + " Time Taken: " + TimeTaken + " minute(s)");
```

int count = 0;
System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(blobClient.OpenRead());

```
            Task<int> task = ComputeDataFromFileAsync(streamReader);
            task.Wait();
            count = Convert.ToInt32(task.Result);
           

            TimeTaken = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime).TotalSeconds * 1.00) / 60), 2);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished Processing " + currFileName + " Count: " + count + " Time Taken: " + TimeTaken + " minute(s)");
```